# Handling carriage return in soap request

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am writing code in PHP to send a soap request using curl. In the soap request I have to send data of a text file which have many Carriage Returns. I have tried sending "carriage return" using \n, \r, \r\n, chr(13) etc but all of these are giving the following error from server

***Lines in the data sent should be delimited by single CR characters only. This file appears to be using LF as a delimiter.***

Following is my Soap request. I am developing in linux and sending request to windows server.

```html
<?php
    $submitFileTxt    .= "Line1 Text"."\r";
    $submitFileTxt    .= "Line2 Text"."\r";
    $submitFIleTxt    .= "Test,Test,Test"."\r";
    $submitFIleTxt    .= "Testtext,Testtext,Testtext"."\r";

    $wsdl   = "somewsdlurl?wsdl"; 
    $local_cert = "certificate file path";
    $password   = '';
    $xml_post_string = "<s:Envelope xmlns:a='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' xmlns:s='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>
    <s:Header>
     <a:Action s:mustUnderstand='1'>Data submit method</a:Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
     <Submit>
     <data xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
      <OutputFileBody>{$submitFIleTxt}</OutputFileBody>
         <OutputFilename>Some file name</OutputFilename>
      </data>
     </Submit>
     </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>";   

   $headers = array(
        "Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
    );  

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,          $wsdl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,   "pem");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,      $local_cert);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,       $local_cert);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    $err = curl_error($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&#13;` in place oo \r and `&#10;` in place of \n.